# How to adjust seek bar of mpMoviePlayerController by Tapping at any Point?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to adjust seek bar of movie player by tapping at any point not by dragging , as apple provides dragging feature.
Kindly suggest me the solution?